# Is there an equivalent to the 'equal' constraint from solidworks in fusion 360?

Tags: cad, solidworks

I used to use Solidworks a few years back and am now trying to learn Autodesk Fusion 360. So far I'm pretty impressed but one thing I've not found is something like the `equal` constraint that Solidworks offered.

My thoughts were that it would clutter a sketch less to make a load of lines constrained to be the same length and then specify the dimension once to lock those constraints down.

Is that possible or is there an equivalent?

Comment: I'm trying to raise my reputation in order to add a tag. If you like the answer, would you please approve it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the Solidworks equal constraint but it sounds like this should be done parametrically in Fusion. Dimension the first line to a value. Then, dimension the second one, but instead of typing in a value, click on the dimension of the first line. It will set it to something like 'd1' and then if you change your first dimension, the second will also change. You can also set them all to a named variable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @ericksonla describes, there is also an equal constraint in Fusion 360 sketching that does exactly what you wish. Maybe this got added since 2017.

[image: snapshot]